# My data frame will not maintain its contents iterating through a nested for loop that appends new rows

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-loops

I am trying to add rows to a data frame by iterating through a nested for loop, one loop iterates through a vector to create another vector, and the other loop iterates though that second vector to extract values. (Not a great explanation, but I'm not sure how else to word it and the code should make apparent what is happening.) However, the data frame resets every time it iterates through the outer loop, even though I cannot find anything in the could that might cause it.

I have tried returning the data frame at different points (at the end of each loop) and different methods of appending the row (`rbind()`, individual elements at a time), with no luck on either front.

```
exp_list is a vector of csv filenames (strings), 
exp_fixmeans creates a vector of numeric values of length fixnum (20, in this case), 
the nested loop goes through each element of the vector and appends the data frame with appropriate values  


#initialization of the data frame
dat <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
x <- c("pupil", "fixnum", "exp")
colnames(dat) <- x

#for loop iterating through experiments
n <- length(exp_list)

for(i in n){
 
  #creates a vector of average pupil size at each fix of the current 
  #experiment
  pupil <- exp_fixmeans(exp_list[i], fixnum)
 
  #iterates through each fixation, appending appropriate values to dat
  for(j in 1:fixnum){
    newrow <- c(as.numeric(pupil[j]), as.numeric(j), exp_list[i])
    dat[nrow(dat)+1,] <- newrow   
  }
}
```

If I pass `exp_list("exp1a", "exp1b", "exp7")` through the for loop, I hope to get back a data frame that has 60 rows, 20 for each fixation of each experiment. However, what I get is a data frame with 20 rows, only of the last experiment in the list (`exp7`, in this case). The rows have correct values, but something is causing it to either not run the previous experiments or delete them upon restarting the inner loop. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The last line within the loop seems like it calls back to the original ‘dat’. Try using ‘rbind’.

Comment: `for(i in n)` should be `for(i in 1:n)`. Or better yet, skip `n` and use `for(i in seq_along(exp_list))`.

Comment: akash's comment isn't your problem, but it is *slightly* more usual to do `dat = rbind(dat, newrow)` then the way you have it. But "growing" a data frame in a loop is terribly inefficient however you do it. Better would be to pre-allocate `dat = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = length(exp_list) * fixnum)` and add to the correct row each time.